# Firebase query returns random user data instead of filtered user data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to fetch data from 'users' collection from data, where the name of user matches/partially matches the searchQuery. My user document has only 3 fields now, 1.name 2.email 3.uid. Im working with firebase for the first time. Help is much appreciated. Here is the code snippet:

```
const results: TeamMemberData[] = [];
        const usersRef = collection(db, "users");
        const q = query(usersRef, where("name", ">=", searchQuery));
        const querySnaphot = await getDocs(q);
          querySnaphot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(doc.data()); // this logs random user data 

            if (currentUser?.email !== doc.data().email)
              results.push({
                name: doc.data().name,
                email: doc.data().email,
                uid: doc.data().uid,
              });
          });
```

[im logging the results here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEFgV.png)
I expected to get the results array would have only those users whose name matched in document in firestore.I only types 'g' but im getting four users, where, three of them doesn't even have 'g' in their name property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got random users because you are using `">="` as [Query operators](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_operators), have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46980648/13488990) how this works when used with strings.

---

In your example you need to use the `==` operator:

```js
const q = query(usersRef, where("name", "==", searchQuery));
```

or maybe [array-contains](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) operator:

```js
const q = query(usersRef, where("name", "array-contains", searchQuery));
```

> This query returns every user document where the name field is an array that contains `searchQuery`. If the array has multiple instances of the value you query on, the document is included in the results only once.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I got to know how to work with strings now.  `const q = query(usersRef, where("name", ">=", searchQuery), where('name','<=', searchQuery + '\uf8ff'));` this query got it done.

Comment: @VatsalDave oh thats nice

Answer (score 0):

u can also try "in" as includes like :

```js
 const q = query(usersRef, where("name", "in", [searchQuery]));
```